# Owlready2 parsing error when calling sync_reasoner

Tags: python, ontology, protege, rdflib, owlready

The ontology was created using protege and populated data from database using the owlready2 library. Now this line is giving this error:

sync_reasoner(my_world)

This is the error I have encountered:

Could not parse ontology.  Either a suitable parser could not be found, or parsing failed.  See parser logs below for explanation. 
The following parsers were tried: 
1) RDFXMLParser 
2) OWLXMLParser 
3) OWLFunctionalSyntaxOWLParser 
4) TurtleOntologyParser 
5) OWLOBOParser 
6) KRSS2OWLParser 
7) ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyParser

### Detailed logs:

```
Parser: RDFXMLParser 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///C:/Users/THARIN~2/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpin0r193y; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 8; Element type "http:" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Parser: OWLXMLParser 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///C:/Users/THARIN~2/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpin0r193y; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 8; Element type "http:" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Parser: OWLFunctionalSyntaxOWLParser 
Encountered " <FULLIRI> "<http://www.semanticweb.org/yashoda/ontologies/2017/12/MovieOnto> "" at line 1, column 1. 
Was expecting: 
    "Ontology" ... 
     (Line 0) 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Parser: TurtleOntologyParser 
uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <ERROR> "< "" at line 64, column 1. 
Was expecting: 
    <EOF>  


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Parser: OWLOBOParser 
org.coode.owlapi.obo.parser.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 941, column 114. 
Was expecting one of: 
    "[" ... 
    <TAG_NAME> ... 
    <QUOTED_STRING> ... 
    <STRING> ... 
    <TAG_VALUE_WS> ... 
    <COMMENT> ... 
     (Line 941) 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Parser: KRSS2OWLParser 
de.uulm.ecs.ai.owlapi.krssparser.ParseException: Encountered " ">" "<http://www.semanticweb.org/yashoda/ontologies/2017/12/MovieOnto> "" at line 1, column 1. 
Was expecting: 
    <EOF>  


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Parser: ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyParser 
Encountered <http://www.semanticweb.org/yashoda/ontologies/2017/12/MovieOnto> at line 1 column 1. Expected one of: 
        Individual: 
        AnnotationProperty: 
        Datatype: 
        DataProperty: 
        ObjectProperty: 
        DisjointProperties: 
        ValuePartition: 
        EquivalentClasses: 
        Import: 
        Prefix: 
        DisjointClasses: 
        Class: 
        SameIndividual: 
        DifferentIndividuals: 
 (Line 1)
```

Comment: Can you post the first ten lines of the file? These are errors from OWLAPI parsing, looks like there is either an error in the ontology file or the format is not a supported one.

Comment: @Ignazio I have edited the question with some lines of ontology file.

Comment: I font believe that is the file being parsed. Many of the parsers say there's an 'http' fragment at line 1, which implies the file should start with that. Is there anything else that could change the file in your code?

Comment: The problem arises when I populate the ontology with mongodb data. before that when I put instances manually it didn't give the exception. The ontology is about movie details

Comment: In that case we need the first ten lines of the ontology with mongodb data

Comment: Please find the complete ontology from the below link. Ontology.owl:  
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1coNZCF0eLoFbCpAUCpdky2H5URr1yTTc

Comment: That's the ontology before data population - it does not match with any of the parse errors you're showing. What does the ontology look like after population? Are there multiple files involved?

Comment: That ontology is giving me the mentioned error. In protege, reasoner works well. but when querying in python it gives the error. I have updated the file and please find it from here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NMpDOWDbIMbfAEwWz4OqvTTtql45VFIn

Answer (score 1):

Far as I can tell (I'm not a Python programmer) Owlready2 is using the HermiT reasoner version 1.3.8 and the embedded OWLAPI version. This version is very ancient - HermiT 1.3.8 uses OWLAPI 3, which has been out of support for a few years now.

The parser errors on this section of the ontology:

```
<Movie rdf:about="#Wonder_Woman_">
  <isMadeIn rdf:resource="#Hong Kong"/>
</Movie>

<Country rdf:about="#Hong Kong">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual"/>
</Country>
```

It is complaining of the `#Hong Kong` fragment - it cannot cope with the space. Changing to:

```
<Movie rdf:about="#Wonder_Woman_">
  <isMadeIn rdf:resource="#Hong_Kong"/>
</Movie>

<Country rdf:about="#Hong_Kong">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual"/>
</Country>
```

allows the parser to cope. Long term, Owlready2 should update to a more recent HermiT release. OWLAPI copes with the file in version 4, and HermiT 1.3.8.413 is the version used in Protege.